# split an html file keeping only the part above a delimiter in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, file, split

I have a html file which contains a string acting as a delimiter and I would like to 
- split this file and keep only the part which is above the delimiter
- close all the opened html tags in the new file.

What would be the best way to do it with ruby (or unix) and keep it efficient.

Thanks in advance
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is store the part of the HTML file that lies before the delimiter, in a string, for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blah</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Some stuff</p>
        <!-- Delimiter --!>
  </body>
</html>
```

And you want everything before the `<!-- Delimiter --!>`

In which case you could probably do this:

```
str = "" 
File.open("the_file.html","r"){|f|str << f.read} #If you need to read the html out of a file
part_to_keep = str.split("<!-- Delimiter --!>").first
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick answer. You have correctly understood my request. I will test your code and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the Unix version you can use a perl one-liner as follows:

```
perl -n -e 'print if $delim;
            $delim=1 if ($delim or /<!-- Delimeter --!>/);' html_file >output
```

This works by using the sentinel variable $delim to detect whether the delimiter has been seen. All lines after the delimiter will then be printed.

Comment: Thanks Mauritz, I have used the ruby code but I keep your solution in my mind.